# 422 (Unprocessable Entity) laravel

Tags: laravel, console

I would like to know if it is normal to have error 422 in the console.

Because I manage the error.

[image]

[image]

Is it okay to see this in the console?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Not a code-breaking error, don't worry.

422 error returned, is probably you have a Request rule that is not satisfied at your API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.
422 is the response that the data you sent is invalid.